# Android Studio Device detection problems

Tags: android

My Android studio isn't detecting my phone or emulator so I can't test run my apps on it. It's telling me "Unable to detect adb version". Please what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is The System Cant Detect `adb.exe` File.

Here is the Solution

1. Download the Platform tools for your platform ([Use This Link](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html))
2. Go to your Android SDK folder
3. Remove old platform-tools
4. Insert platform-tools in the Folder

Hope this May Help You.

Comment: Thanks alot. 
It worked excellently.

Comment: I have done so.